How was the Sanskrit visarga historically pronounced?
I have heard two distinct ways the Sanskrit visarga is pronounced across speakers.
The first is simply as an /h/, that is, the same as ह with a halanta. For instance, नरः would be pronounced "narah" and भूः would be pronounced "bhooh".
The second is as /h+vowel/ where the specific vowel is the vowel just preceding the visarga. For instance, नरः would be pronounced "naraha" and भूः would be pronounced "bhoohoo".
Historically speaking, which one of these, if any, was more prevalent? Did it differ across varieties of Sanskrit? How did Panini pronounce it? What about Vedic Sanskrit?
And also, how do we know? My guess is that poetic metres may help us infer. I think the former pronunciation has one or two less syllable than the latter? So for a line that requires 8 syllables, maybe we can check which pronunciation gives us 8?

In the middle of sentences, the visarga undergoes external sandhi and is either "lost" in the sense that रामः गच्छति becomes रामो गच्छति and so on, or is preserved before क्/ख् or प्/फ् (except if a sibilant immediately follows) where it is supposed to be pronounced as either jihvamuliya [x] or upadhmaniya [ɸ]. This can be heard in recitals of Vedas and even in words like दुःख (note no one pronounces that as दुहुख). However it is not necessary outside of Vedas, and one can pronounce दुःख as du/x/kha or du/h/kha.
At the end of the verse, some schools and pratishakhyas instruct that the visarga is reduplicated (i.e., aha, ihi etc) or elongated (possibly ahhh, ihhh). That, to me, seems to be a way to preserve the sound; as you can imagine, it could easily go unheard or lost in the oral tradition.
However, it is really a breathy /h/ sound, famously, like the hiss of a baby snake according to Yajnavalkya. It represents the lenition of /s/ or /r/ in pausa, and the reason we know that the visarga is really an s/r is because it manifests in sandhi and based on comparisons to other Indo-European languages.
We don't have audio recordings from the past, and Panini and others are only describing what they knew or heard around them.
Edit: Besides being preserved before k/kh/p/ph, the visarga can also preserved before sibilants स् श् ष् where it is supposed to be pronounced like that sibilant. E.g., रामः शिवः च गच्छतः = रामश् शिवश्च गच्छतः . The latter is also acceptable external sandhi where the visarga is lost, but typically the visarga is maintained and only its pronunciation changes.
